# CORS issue on Azure Search to call ListIndexes

Tags: azure, cors, azure-cognitive-search

When trying to call List Indexes endpoint of Search API, seeing a CORS error on pre flight request during development,

API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/list-indexes

[image: Console error]
How can we add I local host as allowed origin in azure search API ?

I did take a look at the existing open bugs but not helping

[CORS issues on Azure Search Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64485513/cors-issues-on-azure-search-service)

[CORS issues on Azure Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862112/cors-issues-on-azure-search)

Calling the list indexes api from local host

API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/list-indexes

Answer (score 0):

For query API's you can follow the below steps:

1. Go to the Azure Portal
2. Go to your Search service resource
3. On the **Overivew** blade, click **Indexes** and navigate to your index
4. Go to the **CORS** tab, select the **Custom** radio button
5. Type "https://localhost:44321" in the Allowed Origins text area

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the REST API to update your Index Definition in the `corsOptions` property.
`

```
"corsOptions": {
    "allowedOrigins": ["https://localhost:44321"]
}
```

`

https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/create-index#request-body

However, as listed in the docs, "For security reasons, only query APIs support CORS. If you want to do other operations such as List Indexes, you will need to setup a proxy to workaround CORS if you wish to list indexes from a website.